# Accessing a datalist element's id using AlpineJS

Tags: alpine.js

Is it possible to get the id value of a selected option in the example below using AlpineJS?

I'm trying to build a form that submits the id of a selected element instead of the value. In this example, when a user selects 'Firefox' from the list and submits the form, the value `1` should be submitted for the value of browserId instead of `Firefox`

```html
<label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>

<input type="text" list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option id=1 value="Firefox">
    <option id=2 value="Edge">
    <option id=3 value="Chrome">
  </datalist>

<input id='browserId' type='hidden' value="Selected Browser's id should show up here"/>
```

I've tried using the `x-model` directive on #browser input element and `x-bind` directive on the #browserId element, but I only get the value and not the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If <datalist> is expendable in favor of <select> you can do this:

```
<div x-data="{browser_id: 1}">

   <label>Choose your browser from the list:</label>

     <select id="browsers" name="browsers" x-on:change="browser_id = $el.value">
       <option value="1">Firefox</option>
       <option value="2">Edge</option>
       <option value="3">Chrome</option>
     </select>

   <input id='browserId' type='hidden' :value="browser_id" />

</div>
```

Comment: Select would not work for me unfortunately. I'm implementing a type to search feature, where the options in the datalist are populated dynamically using HTMX.

Comment: @NFern I think the issue here is more about html than AlpineJS, b/c <select>, <datalist> and all  the inputs based on multiple choices can take the value of the option selected, but NOT its id (that remains a property of the option itself).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I guess I will not be able to use AlpineJS for this use case.

Comment: Maybe you'd better rely on the old dear jQuery => $("#browser").change(function() { $("#browserId”).val() = $(this).children(":selected").attr("id"); });  // NOT TESTED